# construct a complex or statement using values from another table

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a calculated column like this:

```
Unobtainable = 

VAR isUnobtainable = myTable[attribute1] = "FAULTY" || myTable[attribute2] = "FAULTY" || myTable[attribute3] = "FAULTY"

RETURN isUnobtainable
```

Instead of being hardwired like this I want to reference an deviceAttributes table which has a single column attributes with the values attribute1, attribute2, attribute3.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using the Contains. It will return true when any of the rows has the value.

```
Unobtainable = 

VAR isUnobtainable = CONTAINS(DeviceAttr;DeviceAttr[Value];SomeList[Attribute1]) || CONTAINS(DeviceAttr;DeviceAttr[Value];SomeList[Attribute2]) || CONTAINS(DeviceAttr;DeviceAttr[Value];SomeList[Attribute3])


RETURN isUnobtainable
```